# HOw to change the textview size of one class from another class?

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one application.In that I crearte a one cell.That cell contain the one label and textview.In another class i use that cell in tableview.When we click on textview,keyboard will appeard and iam trying to change the textview size.But it was not changing.So please tell me how to solve this one.Methods iam using for creating the cell are below.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
    lbl=[[UILabel alloc]init];
    lbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    txtview=[[UITextView alloc]init];
    txtview.editable=YES;
    //txtview.delegate=self;
    txtview.font=[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:13];
    txtview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    txtview.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically=YES;

    [self.contentView addSubview:lbl];
    [self.contentView addSubview:txtview];

}
return self;
```

}

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

[super layoutSubviews];
lbl.frame=CGRectMake(7,10, 320, 20);

txtview.frame=CGRectMake(0,25, 320,339);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the frame of your textview in customcell. Rather than that set the frame while you are creating cell in your class

```
cell.txtview.frame=CGRectMake(0,25, 320,339);
```

Comment: Have you removed this line(txtview.frame=CGRectMake(0,25, 320,339);) from customcell?

Comment: s.I removed that one.And i mention th etextview size at the time of creating the cell.ANd i change the textview size at the textview delegate methods.But its not working

Comment: You can't do that, why don't you assign the actual size in the starting only.!